# Calling WCF service hosted in Forms Authentication site from a Windows Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, windows-services

We have a Windows Service process that is continually processing messages from a 
Microsoft Messaging Queue. When acting upon these messages, it is calling 
methods from a WCF service.

That WCF service is hosted in an ASP.net web site that not only has the 
WCF services but also an end-user front end. Generally, the WCF methods are 
modifying in-memory data structures, and the front end is reading them. The 
data is constantly being modified and clients need to be notified of changes
immediately. (We are using SignalR.)

Everything was working great as long as the ASP.net site was using Windows 
Integrated authentication. Now it is required that the front end use Forms 
Authentication. This, of course, broke the WCF binding. The previous binding
was:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISessionWebService">
    <security mode="Transport">
      <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
    </security>
  </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Front-end users do not need to be able to call the services. (In fact, they 
should not be able to.)

Ideally, I'd like the WCF service to keep using Windows Authentication and the 
rest of the site to use Forms Authentication, but I don't think IIS supports 
this. I'd prefer not to have to store and pass the password of the account 
running the Windows Service, but if that's the only way, I can live with that. I
was thinking there might be some binding that uses a client certificate, but I
am not sure how that could be set up.

**How can I expose the WCF endpoint in such a way that it is secure and can be
called from the Windows Service?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being easier than I thought. The secret sauce was changing the 
security mode on the binding to `TransportWithMessageCredential`.

From ["Programming WCF Security"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731925(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Transport security depends on the mechanism that the binding you have
>   selected uses. For example, if you are using WSHttpBinding then the
>   security mechanism is Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) (also the mechanism
>   for the HTTPS protocol). Generally speaking, the main advantage of
>   transport security is that it delivers good throughput no matter which
>   transport you are using. However, it does have two limitations: The
>   first is that **the transport mechanism dictates the credential type
>   used to authenticate a user**....

In `TransportWithMessageCredential`, HTTPS is still used to secure the 
transfer of the message, but you are not forced to use the authentication 
scheme of the transport mechanism. So the IIS site can still be set up using 
Forms Authentication but the WCF message authenticated using Windows. The 
binding looks like the following:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
  <binding name="WsHttpEndpoint">
    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
      <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
    </security>
  </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

From there, you can secure the methods of the WCF service using 
`PrincipalPermissionAttribute`, i.e.:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "DOMAIN\\SomeGroup")]
public void DoWork()
{        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK IIS 7 will not allow this, the workarounds seem sketchier than just creating two sites.

You could create two services each on a separate IIS sites on the server. The data service would use `Windows Authentication` and hold the data structures. The front end service would use `Forms Authentication` and then redirect the request to the data service. You could use a custom identity for the app pool for the front end service if you want to exclude other web sites using the ApplicationPool Identity.